# Unit test jest enzyme throws error on Formik 'resetForm'

Tags: react-native, jestjs, enzyme, formik

**I am trying to run unit test (enzyme) throws error on Formik 'resetForm'.**

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'resetForm' of undefined

***FormikForm.js***

```
_handleSubmitPress = (values, { resetForm }) => {
        const { onSubmit } = this.props;

        if (onSubmit) {
            onSubmit({ ...values, resetForm });
        }
    };
```

***UnitTest.js:***

```
it('Should fire formik form submit', () => {
    const UpdateButtonPressMock = jest.fn();
    const component = Component({
        onSubmit: UpdateButtonPressMock,
    });
    expect(component.find(Formik)).toHaveLength(1);
    component.find(Formik)
        .first()
        .simulate('Submit');
    expect(UpdateButtonPressMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

I couldn't find any solution for this error.

Could someone help me on the above? I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [official docs for `simulate`](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/simulate.html), the function signature accepts an optional mock event.

The code you are testing uses properties that are not included in the default `SyntheticEvent` object that `ReactWrapper` passes to your event handler by default, for instance `event.resetForm`.

One way to do this is by triggering Formik's `onSubmit` directly like so:

```js
// UnitTest.js
.simulate("submit", { resetForm: whateverYourMockResetFormValueShouldBe })
component.find(Formik)
  .first()
  .prop('onSubmit')(valuesMock, { resetForm: UpdateButtonPressMock });
expect(UpdateButtonPressMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

I haven't tested this, but you should be able to pass the event along with simulate as well.

```js
// UnitTest.js
component.find(Formik)
  .first()
  .simulate("submit", { resetForm: UpdateButtonPressMock })
expect(UpdateButtonPressMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
```